# freeipa installation issue using kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, freeipa

I'm trying to deploy freeipa using a deployment yaml file using my Kubernetes cluster , my OS is Rocky9, my deployment yaml is:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
        name: ipa-test
        labels:
                app: ipa
spec:
        replicas: 1
        selector:
            matchLabels:
              app: ipa
        template:
                metadata:
                        name: ipa
                        labels:
                                app: ipa

                spec:
                        containers:

                                - name: ipa
                                  image: git.elcld.net:9000/slatif/ast_ccx_api/freeipa:v2
                                  args: ["ipa-server-install","-U","-r","DEV.ELCLD.NET","--no-ntp"]
                                  env:
                                    - name: IPA_SERVER_HOSTNAME
                                      value: dailywagesipa.dev.elcld.net
                                    - name: PASSWORD
                                      value: bNnK^28NXEGsiL#
                                  securityContext:
                                    privileged: true
                                  volumeMounts:
                                  - name: data-test
                                    mountPath: /data:Z
                                  - name: dshm
                                    mountPath: /dev/shm

                        volumes:
                          - name: dshm
                            emptyDir:
                              medium: Memory
                          - name: data-test
                            nfs:
                              path: /ifs/AR2-PSC/ipatest/ipa-data/
                              server: pscl-nfs.elcld.net


                        imagePullSecrets:
                          - name: regcred
```

PS: I already ran the podman build -t Dockerfile for Rocky9 and then uploaded the podman image to my registry.

the pod is running the `ipa-server-install` command and it's reaching this point then fails

```
 [10/10]: starting directory server
Done.
Restarting the KDC
Configuring SID generation
  [1/8]: adding RID bases
  [2/8]: creating samba domain object
  [3/8]: adding admin(group) SIDs
  [4/8]: updating Kerberos config
'dns_lookup_kdc' already set to 'true', nothing to do.
  [5/8]: activating sidgen task
  [6/8]: restarting Directory Server to take MS PAC and LDAP plugins changes into account
  [7/8]: adding fallback group
  [8/8]: adding SIDs to existing users and groups
This step may take considerable amount of time, please wait..
Done.
Configuring client side components
This program will set up IPA client.
Version 4.10.2


FreeIPA server configuration failed.
```

After i inspected the logs of the `/var/log/ipaclient-install.log` i saw this error

```
    plugins = schema.get_package(server_info, client)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipaclient/remote_plugins/schema.py", line 546, in get_package
    schema = Schema(client)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipaclient/remote_plugins/schema.py", line 395, in __init__
    fingerprint, ttl = self._fetch(client, ignore_cache=read_failed)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipaclient/remote_plugins/schema.py", line 420, in _fetch
    schema = client.forward(u'schema', **kwargs)['result']
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipalib/rpc.py", line 1146, in forward
    return self._call_command(command, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipalib/rpc.py", line 1122, in _call_command
    return command(*params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipalib/rpc.py", line 1276, in _call
    return self.__request(name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipalib/rpc.py", line 1239, in __request
    response = self.__transport.request(
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1166, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipalib/rpc.py", line 724, in single_request
    if not self._auth_complete(response):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipalib/rpc.py", line 673, in _auth_complete
    raise errors.KerberosError(

2024-03-02T08:48:43Z DEBUG The ipa-client-install command failed, exception: KerberosError: No valid Negotiate header in server response
2024-03-02T08:48:43Z ERROR No valid Negotiate header in server response
2024-03-02T08:48:43Z ERROR The ipa-client-install command failed. See /var/log/ipaclient-install.log for more information
```

Anyone faced this issue before ? any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it resolved by changing the image from rocky9 to fedoria